# Store JSON data into model class array in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to store the fetched JSON data to my model class array propertyArray. Some how I got the JSON data using Alamofire library and now I want to parse that data to the properties of PropertyList model class. I am not able to parse JSON data to propertyArray. I referred many other solutions to this question on stack overflow but did not get any appropriate solution.

**Declared Model Class Array**

```
var propertyArray: [PropertyList]? = []
```

**Alamofire Function**

```
func dataPass()  {
    print("Landlord id is \(land.id)")
    let  para: Parameters = ["id": land.id]
    Alamofire.request(URL_Landlord_Property_List, method: .post, parameters: para).responseJSON { response in
        if let dictionary = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
            var prop = PropertyList()
            let data = dictionary["data"] as! [Any]
            print(data)
        }
    }
}
```

**PropertyList**

```
import Foundation

struct PropertyList{
    var property_id: String?
    var user_id: String?
    var property_code: String?
    var property_added_date: String?
    var property_updated_date: String?
    var property_termination_date: String?
    var property_ASYS_no: String?
    var propertyCode: String?
    var property_address_1:String?
    var property_address_2: String?
    var property_address_3: String?
    var property_city: String?
    var property_cluster:String?
    var property_area:String?
    var property_postcode: String?
    var property_landlord_ref_code: String?
    var property_landlord_id: String?
}
```

**JSON Data**

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "property_id": "1",
      "user_id": "1",
      "property_code": "0001",
      "property_added_date": "2017-12-13",
      "property_updated_date": "2017-12-13 00:00:00",
      "property_termination_date": null,
      "property_ASYS_no": "ASYS 001",
      "propertyCode": "0001-PUNE1",
      "property_address_1": "PUNE1",
      "property_address_2": "PUNE2",
      "property_address_3": "PUNE3",
      "property_city": "PUNE",
      "property_cluster": "1",
      "property_area": "1",
      "property_postcode": "424031",
      "property_landlord_ref_code": null,
      "property_landlord_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "property_id": "2",
      "user_id": "1",
      "property_code": "0002",
      "property_added_date": "2017-12-14",
      "property_updated_date": "2017-12-18 00:00:00",
      "property_termination_date": null,
      "property_ASYS_no": "asys 0200",
      "propertyCode": "0002-hadpasar1",
      "property_address_1": "hadpasar1",
      "property_address_2": "hadpasar2",
      "property_address_3": "hadpasar3",
      "property_city": "pune",
      "property_cluster": "9",
      "property_area": "2",
      "property_postcode": "012121",
      "property_landlord_ref_code": null,
      "property_landlord_id": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What actually happens when you run the code you have so far? What further help do you need? There are countless examples and tutorials about this.

Comment: I want to see my JSON data into my array but I don't know how to do that within alamofire.

Comment: Yes, that's clear. Please read my first comment again. Clearly explain what your actual issue is with the code you posted.

Comment: How can i access the JSON tree objects? If I am able to access the tree, I want to assign them to the model class properties

Comment: @rmaddy Sir, I have recently started programming in swift. So I need some basic guidance from my friends here regarding the same.

Comment: Start by searching for one of the countless tutorials on parsing JSON with Swift. Or find one of [the many, many existing topics](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+parse+json+alamofire) here on the subject.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks alot. I definitely check the link you provided. Hope I find the solution soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your JSON is an array that contains dictionaries. (Key-Value data structure)

This should do the trick.

```
 let data = dictionary["data"] as! [[String: Any]]
```

Then parse it inside your constructor:

```
struct PropertyList{

    init(dict: [String: Any){
     //parse here...
       self.property_id = dict["property_id"] as! String
    }

}
```

To add to array:

```
 for dict in data{
      let propertyList = PropertyList(dict: dict)
      propertyArray.append(propertyList)
 }
```

Comment: Yes. My array is a key-value data. I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: Yes. See my app processing goes like - Firstly, I need to JSON data into my code so I chose Alamofire for fetching JSON data from URL. Then, I want to assign the JSON data to the model class array propertyArray. Later, I will use the array to populate my table view

Comment: I literally gave you the answer from the top. You have the dictionary, now you just need to assign it your properties...

Comment: Exactly. I don't know how to assign them to properties

Comment: Sorry. I did not checked your answer.

Comment: I am facing problem in Model class PropertyList. Attaching screenshot of my issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162959/discussion-between-saurabh-and-huy-vo).

Comment: It seems like the questions isn't really iOS questions but modern tech questions such as "how do I handle JSON?".

Comment: The problem i am facing now is not a silly one. Thanks for your help though.